# Error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

```
template <class ST>
bool OrderedSet<ST>::IsIn (const ST & value) const
{
    for (LNode * np = first; np != NULL; np = np -> next)
        if (np -> next == value)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

I understand that np->next is a pointer and value is not.  I want to return true if the specified data value is in the set and false if the value is not in the set.

Comment: There better be something else in that struct besides a `next` pointer. Try comparing *that* to the passed `value` rather than the linked list management field you're currently using.

Comment: *I understand that np->next is a pointer and value is not.* So, why don't you correct it?

Comment: Your question is way inclomplete, regarding giving us enough information to diagnose this! What's the declaration of `OrderedSet`, where are values held there??

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
if (np -> next == value)
```

should be

```
if (np->data == value)
```

except that we don't actually know what your `data` member variable is named.